# How to get the file absolute path in JAVA project

Tags: java

Hi I need to read the file by using FileInputStream but I didn't get the right path. My file is location at C:\Users\tester\Documents\Java Project\Samples\ProjectOne\src\pdfReader
However when I used the below code, I get the wrong path that is 
"/C:/Users/tester/Documents/Java%20Project/Samples/ProjectOne/bin/ProjectOne/TestFile.txt"

There is my code:

```
String filePath;
filePath=MainForm.class.getResource("TestFile.txt").getPath();
```

Would someone tell me how to get the file path?

Comment: Are you sure the file is not actually in the `bin` folder? Eclipse might have copied it automatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606503/java-get-absolute-path-of-project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using Eclipse and as you have saved the file `TestFile.txt` inside your source folder, it is being copied to the `bin` folder, the output folder of your project. Therefore, the path is not wrong. As in your code you use `getResource` method, the file will be retrieved from the same directory where your `MainForm.class` was found.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

If you really want to get such file from your source folder, then you should do something like this:

```
System.out.println(new File("src/pdfReader/TestFile.txt").getAbsolutePath());
```

However, if you are planning to distribute your application it would be better to store this kind of file in a `resources` folder because source folders are usually not included in `dist` packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `file` and use `getAbsolutePath` method:

```
File file = new File("TestFile.txt");//full file path URL
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Here is the simple programme:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = null;
    String path = "";
    boolean bool = false;
    try {
        // create new files
        f = new File("test.txt");
        // returns true if the file exists
        bool = f.exists();
        // if file exists
        if (bool) {
            // get absolute path
            path = f.getAbsolutePath();
            // prints
            System.out.print("Absolute Pathname " + path);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if any error occurs
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```